# Attach a return false to jquery bind

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this code:

```
$('#la_freccia_dx').bind('click', function(){
 boutique_next();   
});
```

In my html markup I prevent the page to scroll up using this code:

```
<a id="la_freccia_dx" href="#" onclick="boutique_next(); return false;">
```

But now it works only for the first time I click the link. I need to attach the return false to my jquery function up above and prevent the default action of the link. Any idea?
Thanks!

**SOLVED: MY FAULT! I left a href="#" in the markup. Thanks everyone!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuerys "event.preventDefault()":

```
$('#la_freccia_dx').bind('click', function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 boutique_next();
});
```

I would have done it like this:

```
$('#la_freccia_dx').click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 boutique_next();
});
```

With my HTML as:

```
<a id="la_freccia_dx">
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks James! I tried this before but your html suggestion made me realize that i left a href="#" in my link!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$('#la_freccia_dx').on('click', function(){
 boutique_next(); 
 return false;  
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work the page still scrolls up to the DIV this link is changing.

Comment: Try <a id="la_freccia_dx" href="#"> remove this onclick="boutique_next(); return false;"

Comment: @SeccoJones: don't blame others for your faults. The answer is correct and working.